# How to work with dynamic values in redirect URIs (Azure AD)

Tags: azure-active-directory

I know that Azure AD App registration does not allow wildcards in redirect URIs and that **RFC 6819** is really strict about it. But in our CI/CD workflow we generate a new review app, with a dynamic URL, for each new Merge Request. So if I have two Merge Requests awaiting for review, *'my-mr-1'* and *'my-mr-2'*, I'll have two new generated web apps with their own dynamic URIS:

https://app-review-mymr1.domain.com/
https://app-review-mymr2.domain.com/

Any way to allow a redirect URI in Azure AD to work for everything like https://app-review-*.domain.com/?

Thanks!

Comment: You could have a step in your CI pipeline that adds the URL to reply URLs maybe? E.g. through Azure AD PowerShell. Those would need to be cleaned up after some time though.

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#restrictions-on-wildcards-in-redirect-uris

According to this document, you can set wildcard in the URIs with some restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was true back in July, 2019. But it's no supported anymore on the Azure Portal UI. The URI is simply invalid if you try to put a wildcard.

Comment: @amachado It's possible to set wildcard by editing the manifest. And it worked for me.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work. When I save I get a error message: "Failed to update application. Error detail: Invalid value specified for property 'replyUrlsWithType' of resource 'Application'. [kKh6k]"

Comment: I got it. You must have created the app with account type "organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts". As the link in my original comment mentions, wildcard can be specified to the "apps that sign in work or school accounts".  Using wildcard, you have to create the app with account type "this organizational directory only" or "any organizational directory".

Answer (score 0):

The Ui has restictions but the cli does not. you can do

```
az ad app update --id <app-id> --add replyUrls "https://*.domain.com/"
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't seem to work anymore either; It gives `Invalid value specified for property 'replyUrls' of resource 'Application'.` as an error. Same behavior when editing the manifest directly on the portal.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully updated through CLI

```
az ad app update --id <id> --web-redirect-uris "https://*.mydomain.example.com"
```

Comment: This unfortunately results in "Reply url is not well formed." for me.